# Why did they only show the miniaturisation of men?

Tags: downsizing-2017

In the sci-fi comedy *Downsizing*, we see a a lady picking up a shrunk man with a paddle and putting him onto a miniature gurney.

[image: A woman picks up a shrunken man, she wears a white lab coat and gloves, 2 others are working in the background]

Why did they only show the shrinking procedure of men?

Comment: I'm not sure if "comedy" should be in quotes here. The film had some funny *moments*, but it wasn't much of a comedy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the men's facility. Evidently there's a women's facility as well, which makes good sense given that women are likely to have different medical requirements for downsizing, such as the removal of implanted IUDs and breast implants. Also, the procedure requires the removal of hair which [certain religions](https://www.bostonglobe.com/metro/2014/11/07/cambridge-haven-for-muslim-women-get-their-hair-cut-and-styled-private/dggZp6EDxUyzVZCSHrWuYO/story.html) would forbid in the presence of a man.

From the [original screenplay](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/downsizing.pdf);

> **NURSE:** *Someone will escort you to **the Women’s Facility** shortly. You will be separated for approximately five hours, and following the procedure you’ll be reunited in the recovery room.*

It's also worth noting that the medication seems to be tailored to men and women, adults and children ("*Single dosage - Adult - Male*"). Having them all jumbled together would likely cause a higher risk of an incident occurring.

[image: A bottle of the "Downsizing Solution" for men as quoted above]

Comment: Due to the number of women (nurses or doctors) in the men’s facility, this doesn’t appear to be a Muslim-friendly venue.

Comment: @Laurel - Muslim men tend to be far more tolerant of female doctors, nurses and hairdressers, at least in the Western world.